# Why is the ablative used here instead of the genitive

Tags: vulgata, ablative

Mark 1:6 starts with

> Et erat Joannes vestitus pilis cameli...

Which is translated as "John was clothed with camel's hairs...."

Why is it pilis instead of pilorum?  Shouldn't pilis use genitive since it modifies vestitus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **pilus** → *hair* / **pilis** → *by/with hairs* (ablative) or *to hairs* (dative)
- **camelus** → *camel* / **cameli** → *camel's, of [a/the] camel*

Basically the genitive indicates that *cameli* is complementing the noun, specifying what kind of hairs are being talked about: those of a camel.

If *pilorum* was used instead, it would translate to *of [the] hairs*, and it would need to modify some other noun (e.g. **colore pilorum cameli** → *with the color of a camel's hairs*)

Now the ablative in **pilis** means the whole **pilis cameli** is an [adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) indicating the instrument used *to accomplish the action* (i.e., to get/be dresseed)